# ExtJS: text beneath image of unknown height

Tags: css, extjs

I'm using ExtJS 5.

I have a window. Inside I need an image and a text below the image. Image can be changed in runtime, so I can't set its height.

Currently I have:

```
Ext.define('SystemMonitor.view.AboutWindow', {
    extend: Ext.window.Window,
    layout: 'vbox',
    height: 420,
    width: 652,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'image',
            width: '100%',
            //autoEl: 'div',
            //height: '100%',
            src: 'resources/images/about.png'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: 'vbox',
            //liquidLayout: true,
            padding: 10,
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'label',
                    text: 'Server Monitor'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'label',
                    text: '(c) 2016'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Image has 100% of its parent (window). But container for labels is rendered at top of window with image as background. It has class x-box-item and CSS:

```
element.style {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
    right: auto;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0;
}
.x-box-item {
    position: absolute !important;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0;
}
```

When I uncomment `liquidLayout` the element (container) does not have `top: 0` but then this property is taken from class `x-box-item`.

How can I position container below image? I have a concept of rendering all in HTML and then it is very easy task but I prefer to achieve this using ExtJS components.

Comment: why are you set the position to absolute? let ext do the layout issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put everything in yet another container and this new container lays everything correctly

```
Ext.define('SystemMonitor.view.AboutWindow', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    height: 420,
    width: 652,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'image',
                    width: '100%',
                    src: 'resources/images/about.png'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    cls: 'page-content',
                    layout: {
                        type: 'vbox',
                        align: 'stretch'
                    },
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'label',
                            itemId: 'softwareTitleAndVersion',
                            text: 'System Monitor '
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'label',
                            itemId: 'copyright'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```